# Tensorflow: Combining Loss Functions in LSTM Model for Domain Adaptation

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, lstm

Can any one please help me out?

I am working on my thesis work. Its about Predicting Parkinson disease, Since i want to build an LSTM model to adapt independent of patients. Currently i have implemented it using TensorFlow with my own loss function.

Since i am planning to introduce both labeled train and unlabeled train data in every batch of data to train the model. I want to apply my own loss function on this both labeled and unlabeled train data and also want to apply cross entropy loss only on labeled train data. Can i do this in tensorflow?

So my question is, Can i have combination of loss functions in a single model training on different set of train data?

Answer (score 0):

From an implementation perspective, the short answer would be yes. However, I believe your question could be more specific, maybe what you mean is whether you could do it with tf.estimator?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!, can you have any example as such using tf.estimator, That will really help me